# Android Exception trying to open a new Activity - Surface::lock failed, already locked

Tags: android, exception, android-layout, android-activity

When I try to open a new activity on a button press i get an Exception :

```
01-19 14:55:08.327: E/Surface(15454): Surface::lock failed, already locked
01-19 14:55:08.327: E/SurfaceHolder(15454): Exception locking surface
01-19 14:55:08.327: E/SurfaceHolder(15454): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I have a game that draws on a surfaceview canvas with a thread, that runs with the main process, I'm trying to open a new dialog box for input and nothing worked so I'm simply trying to open a new Activity that will Exception, I'm using the lock and unlock and well synchronized, I tried stopping the thread and even placing a couple of views.
Any help is good Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect your rendering thread is locking the surface after onPause() is called. Don't do that.

In your Activity's onPause() you should tell your rendering thread to wait (outside the canvas lock/unlock) and then let it run again in onResume().

A simple approach to doing this would be to create the rendering thread in onResume(), and then in onPause() signal that it should exit (maybe by setting a boolean value read in the thread loop) and then also wait for it to exit (via Thread.join()) before returning from onPause().